# Internet connection for MPI cluster

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, mpi, ip-address, subnet

I am working on a project that involves multiple rpi's all running MPI. My MPI is working, but I have it configured to my home network and using those IP. is it possible to generate an IP for every single node and use those IP's to have the nodes communicate instead of having it through an actual network? They are all connected to the same switch and would be on the same subnet.

Comment: Added tag. I had to think for quite a while to get what is your "rpi".

Answer (score 2):

Everything old is new again.   In the late 90s we had "beowulf clusters" that were not so different from your rpi setup.

you would take 8 machines (I did say it was the late 90s) and call one of them the "head node".  This head node might have two NICs, one public facing (on your home network) and the other cluster-facing.  The cluster-facing nic and all the non-head-nodes would be on one of the internal-only private IP subnets (typically 192.168.yyy.xxx or 10.xxx.yyy.zzz because none of us could remember where the 172.whatever network began/ended)

You can get fancy and have your head node be a dhcp server, or you can just statically assign each node an ip address and hostname.

The important bit about this design is your head node does not route ip traffic.  You can ssh to it, then ssh from it to the slave nodes (if need be), but the head node is the only one that gets out to the rest of the world.

Comment: Awesome! I will try that Out. thank you for the insight!